# How to append JSON response output into html table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, html-table, response

I have this response output (type JSON)--> pass from controller

[["Subash Nisam",test,"Medix Care","2017.03.02","9.30 am to 10.30 am"],["Subash Nisam",test,"Medix Care","2017.03.02","3.30 to 5.30"]]

I want to append it following table tbody using Javascript-->

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="doctorresultTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Doctor Name</th>
            <th>Speciality</th>
            <th>Hospital</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do it?

Here is my JS code:

```
function searchbyNameandDate(name, avadate) {
    var ajaxConfig = {
        type: "GET",
        url: "searchbyNameandDate?name=" + name + "&date=" + avadate,
        async: true,
        dataType: "json"
    };
    $.ajax(ajaxConfig)
            .done(function (response) {

                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

                        var html = "<tr> \
                <td>" + response[i][j] + "</td> \
                <td>" + response[i][j] + "</td>\
                <td>" + response[i][j] + "</td> \
                <td>" + response[i][j] + "</td> \
                <td>" + response[i][j] + "</td> \
            </tr>";
                        $("#doctorresultTable tbody").append(html);
                    }

                }


            })
            .fail(function (xhr, status, errorMessage) {
                alert("failed to load data");
                console.log("XML HTTP REQUEST : " + xhr);
                console.log("Status : " + status);
                console.log("Error message : " + errorMessage);
            });
    }

}
```

Comment: can i see your code? what u tried so far

Comment: I've submitted my js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using plain javascript (ES6):

```js
const data = [["Subash Nisam",'test',"Medix Care","2017.03.02","9.30 am to 10.30 am"],["Subash Nisam",'test',"Medix Care","2017.03.02","3.30 to 5.30"]];

var tableContent = document.querySelector('#doctorresultTable > tbody');
data.map(instance => {
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  tableContent.appendChild(row);
  instance.map(info => {
    const cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.innerText = info;
    row.appendChild(cell);
  });
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="doctorresultTable">
            <thead
                <tr>
                    <th>Doctor Name</th>
                    <th>Speciality</th>
                    <th>Hospital</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Though it would be easier to use some framework like Angular or React for rendering the view (React is preferable if you don't need to build an entire application).

Comment: It's worked. can you suggest me a preferred tutorial or reference for improve my js knowledge.

Comment: I've problem when run with your code. when it runs console output show this---> Unexpected token >       It gives error is here--> " data.map(instance = > {"

Comment: You can look into [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp), as your question was referring to DOM manipulations. And you also can take a look at how jQuery and React are used to manipulate the DOM, there are lots of online tutorials

Comment: What browser do you use? By the way, this is ES6, so you're probably going to need a transpiler (like Babel), or just replace the arrow functions with usual functions

Answer (score 1):

I replace the arrow functions with usual functions.
Now it's work properly. 
-------------------------@Armen Vardanyan ->Thanks for your help.

Here is the code after replace the arrow functions with usual functions.

```
const data = [["Subash Nisam",'test',"Medix Care","2017.03.02","9.30 am to 10.30 am"],["Subash Nisam",'test',"Medix Care","2017.03.02","3.30 to 5.30"]];

var tableContent = document.querySelector('#doctorresultTable > tbody');
data.map(function(instance) {
 const row = document.createElement('tr');
 tableContent.appendChild(row);
 instance.map(function(info) {
  const cell = document.createElement('td');
  cell.innerText = info;
  row.appendChild(cell);
 });
});
```